# slowcheetah: how to add an existing file as a transform

Tags: visual-studio, transform, slowcheetah

I'm using SlowCheetah for config transforms with VS2013.
let's say I get  web.config and web.debug.config files via an external source, for some reason.

How can I import both files in my solution and have SlowCheetah detect the transform relation? I know I can manually change the csproj file to do it, but can it be done automatically?

As a side question if the web.config would already be in the project could I add the web.debug.config as a transform?

What I'm doing now is select add transform, which may add several more transform for test, staging and so on. Then I delete the ones I don't need and finally I open the transforms and copy the content manually..

This action doesn't happen that often, but it bugs me when it does.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need SlowCheetah for ASP.NET web.config transforms, this is built-in. Only for console-applications app.config (which don't support transforms out-of-the-box).

Regarding the import of configs, did you try to copy/download the files in your directory on the Pre-build event in the .csproj file -> Build events?

Comment: No I haven't. It's not an action that I have to do a lot.

Comment: The relation is dependent on the Build Configuration you are using to build the project (Debug/Release are default). You can create custom Build Configurations and in the filename, replace the .debug. part with .<build-config-name>. part. Transforms are then automatically picked up. **knocks on wood**

Comment: This is only for when you build. I was talking about the dev stage. Let's say I have a new project and in a previous project I had x.config and x.debug.config. Now I want to add those files in my new project. If I just copy-paste I'll have 2 config instead of one, with a transform